# white space between 2 divs?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs and in between these two divs is some sort of white space I cannot seem to get rid of.  Here is the jsfiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/aBzPv/1/

Basically one div is a menu (a vertical list) at the top of my page.  I want to create another div directly underneath it for "Recent Items".  I noticed that there is just too much white space between my first div (corp-crumb) with my second div (recent-crumb):

```
<div>
            <div id="corp-crumb">
                <ul class="vertlist" id="ulTop">
                    <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="createNewLink" href="#" title="Create New" class="crumblink">Create New</a>
                         <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Company">Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
            </div> 
            <div id="recent-crumb">hello world what is this white space here ^^^^^^^^</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Some of the CSS:

```
#corp-crumb {
    background: rgb(252, 252, 252); 
    margin: 0px -12px 20px; 
    padding: 0px 10px; 
    /*overflow: hidden;*/ 
    font-size: 11px; 
    border-bottom-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); 
    border-bottom-width: 1px; 
    border-bottom-style: solid; 
    min-height: 28px;
}

#recent-crumb {
    background: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    margin: 0px -12px;
    padding: 0px 10px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px; 
    border-bottom-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); 
    border-bottom-width: 1px; 
    border-bottom-style: solid; 
    min-height: 28px;
}

.vertlist ul {
    margin: 0px 2em 0px 3.6em; 
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

img
{
    border-style:none;
}

.vertlist li
{
   display:block;
   float:left;
   width:140px; 
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:small;
   height:50px;
   list-style:none;
}

ul.vertlist li.submenu ul li {
   display: block;
   padding: 3px 8px;
   /*#E5F1FA*/
   background: rgb(252, 252, 252);
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:thin;
   border-color:rgb(242, 242, 242);
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: small;
 }

ul.vertlist li.submenu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #E5F1FA;  
}

ul.vertlist li.submenu ul:hover {
    background-color: #E5F1FA;  
}

ul.vertlist li.crumblink.submenu:hover {
    background-color: #E5F1FA;
}

ul.corp-footer-local li.crumblink.submenu ul li:hover {
   background-color: #E5F1FA; 
}

a.crumblink:hover {
   background-color: #E5F1FA; 
}

ul.vertlist li ul 
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

ul.vertlist li.submenu:hover ul 
{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:9999;
    visibility: visible;    
}

ul.vertlist li:hover ul, ul.vertlist li.hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; 
}

ul.vertlist li:hover li, ul.vertlist li.hover li {
   float: none;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBzPv/1/) for demonstration.

Comment: is it the bottom margin set in `#corp-crumb`?  You have a top margin of `0`, left and right margins of `-12px` and a bottom margin of `20px`.

Comment: I tried removing that to no avail, you can even try to remove it in the fiddle, the white space still exists.

Comment: Just so you know, you're missing a closing `</ul>` after your last `</li>` tag.

Comment: Copy paste error i will fix tylerh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's make your code more elegant, don't worry - just few steps to go.

1. First of all, you have margin bottom on your `#corp-crumb`, remove it.
2. Remove browser-specific margins from the `ul.vertlist` and `ul.vertlist ul` by adding `margin:0;` to your code. (the same happens to headings, so be aware of that)
3. Remove margin-top from `#recent-crumb`
4. Change height of `.vertlist li`, because it's bigger then container's one and makes your `#recent-crumb` moved to the right side. The height should be the same as container, in your case -`height: 29px`.
5. And the last thing, remove browser-specific margins from body by adding `margin:0px;` to it.

PS. Use [`normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to avoid browser-specific paddings and margins to e.g. `<body>` and `<ul>` (we have already fixed that in point #2 and #5). Don't use negative margins on divs instead, it's not a good alternative (and not cross-browser).

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aBzPv/5/

As suggested in the comments, change your CSS from:

```
ul.vertlist li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

to

```
ul.vertlist li ul {
   display:none;
}
```

and then remove `visiblity:visible` from `ul.vertlist li.submenu:hover ul`. It's better approach.

Comment: and the ul seems to have just `visibility:hidden` or something.  That submenu really needs `position:absolute` to work

Comment: This appears to help me, however the content of the div seems to be floated to the right...but I believe it is because I need to clear:both for the divs.  However, this causes an additional spacing between my corp-crumb and recent-crumb yet still.  For instance, use the fiddle and make a lot more li items in the corp-crumb.

Comment: If the divs are supposed to be one under another, no need for using floats. Try to remove them. @JonH, if you want, past here your JSFiddle now (with errors you get), we will try to see what's missing.

Comment: Is there any way to take this to a chat?  Because this is still not working for me...

Comment: Hard to explain my issue as I am not a css person, however I have inherited this :).  My issue is the recent-crumb seems to be shifted to the right, but I noticed that is where the last li item is from corp-crumb.  If I do something like <div class="clear"></div> where clear simply is a style of `clear:both;` it moves recent-crumb the way I want but now there is a lot of white space between the corp-crumb and recent-crumb.

Comment: @MikeGrabowski I am back sorry about that.

Comment: @JonH glad could help, on private chat as well. You can mark my answer with green tick ;)

Comment: @MikeGrabowski - Are you still around? I changed to a jquery ui menu and have the same exact issue now!

Comment: Send me an email @JonH, will be back Home in few hours. We can chat tommorow.

Comment: I mailed you yesterday, check your spam box just in case

Comment: I checked and nothing...I just need to discuss in less than five minutes, can you ping me when you get home?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51764/discussion-between-jonh-and-mike-grabowski)

Comment: @MikeGrabowski - do you have a minute to look at this?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, open your dev tools.

Then in the elements tab. select and hover on #corp-crumb.

Now, in the upper right panel, you see div#corp-crumb as a blue rectangle, and an orange rectangle under it. This is margin, as you can see in the lower right pane (with the same color schema). Green, to the left, is padding

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`20px` value causes that in `#corp-crumb`:

```
margin: 0px -12px 20px;
```